# Position window automaticly in TWM

Tags: xorg, twm, xinit

The [man pages](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/twm.1.html) of TWM tells me that if I specify a `-geometry [size x size] + offset + offset`, TWM will honor this and create the window in that location.

For which types of windows is this possible? It is possible to set a geometry for xclock and xterm, but not for gvim. How can I initially position gvim - for example -  at a given position on my screen?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately is is up to each individual application to parse its own command line options, so some may support a `-geometry` option and some won't. You will have to check the man page or usage message for each application.

It's worth nothing that `gvim` does seem to have a working `-geometry` option, at least on my system.